# Как создать изображение из текста?

Tags: java, изображения

Надо сделать так: например, вбиваю "Hello, World!", и на выходе получаю картинку 100 на 300 px, по центру которой написан набранный текст нужным цветом, шрифтом и на определенном фоне.

Что-то вроде формирования иконок и плашек, для которых не загрузили изображение.

Comment: Вот [в данной теме](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800717/convert-text-content-to-image) есть пример.

Comment: @Wolkodav не могу не отметить ваши с artwolf замечательные ники :)